# Resize icons in Rating Bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am developing in android using Samsung S3 device and Samsung Galaxy tab 2 10.1 device.

I have a Progress Bar and I'm using shared icon stars for the two devices but while Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 correctly displays the 5 stars, with Samsung S3 device only 4 stars are displayed because they are too big.

I tried:

- to put the stars in different size resources folders but both devices load the xhdpi stars;
- to create a different style for the Samsung S3 device with minHeight and maxHeight but the stars were cut horizontally and not resized;

what can I do to correctly resize the stars icons for both devices?
I really don't like to create ad-hoc stars for each device but it would be nice to reuse the images.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try using *"android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"* in your ratingbar,

if you want even smaller rating bar style *"?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"*  but this make rating lil more small

[for more information you can refer](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/)